# About linearization around an equilibrium point

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-system, linearization

Consider the following non-linear differential equation
$$\label{star}
\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t))+g(x(t),u(t)), \quad t\ge 0, \ x(0)=x_0\in\mathbb{R},\tag{$\star$}
$$
where $f(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$ are smooth functions of their arguments and $u(t)$, $t\ge 0$ is an input function. Suppose that the input dynamics satisfy another differential equation
$$\label{u}
\dot{u}(t) = h(u(t)) + z(x(t)), \quad t\ge 0, \ u(0)=u_0\in\mathbb{R},\tag{$\#$}
$$
where $h(\cdot)$ and $z(\cdot)$ are smooth functions.

Moreover suppose that $(x^*(t),u^*(t))=(0,\bar{u}(t))$, where $\dot{\bar{u}}(t) = h(\bar{u}(t))$, $\bar{u}(0)=u_0$, is an equilibrium for the system in \eqref{star}. The task is to linearize \eqref{star} around $(x^*(t),u^*(t))$.

> **My (perhaps silly) question.** Is the following one the correct linearized dynamics?
>   $$
> \dot{\delta_x}(t) = \frac{\mathrm{d} f(x)}{\mathrm{d} x}\bigg|_{x=0}\delta_x(t)+\frac{\partial g(x,u)}{\partial x}\bigg|_{x=0,u=\bar{u}}\delta_x(t)+\frac{\partial g(x,u)}{\partial u}\bigg|_{x=0,u=\bar{u}}\delta_u(t).
> $$
>   If so, since the dynamics of $u(t)$ depends on $x(t)$ from \eqref{u}, when I explicitly compute the derivatives $\frac{\partial g(x,u)}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial g(x,u)}{\partial u}$ do I also  need to evaluate the derivatives $\frac{\mathrm{d} u}{\mathrm{d} x}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} u}$?

Comment: $(*)$+$(\#)$ is a "good" system of (autonomous) ODEs, and its linearization is $$\begin{bmatrix}\dot{\delta}_x\\\dot{\delta}_u\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{df}{dx}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\\\frac{dz}{dx}&\frac{dh}{du}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\delta_x\\\delta_u\end{bmatrix}.$$ So, even if we take $\delta_u(0)=0$ we have still $\dot{\delta}_u(t)=\frac{dz}{dx}(x(t))\,\delta_x(t)$.

Comment: @user539887: Thanks for your comment! Suppose that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\big|_{x=x^*,u=u^*}=0$. Then the dynamics of $\delta_x$ and $\delta_u$ should be decoupled and so the linearized dynamics of $x$ around $(x^*,u^*)$ should read as $\dot{\delta}_x(t)=\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\big|_{x=x^*}{\delta}_x(t)+\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\big|_{x=x^*,u=u^*}{\delta}_x(t)$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, if this is what you call "decoupling".  I just browsed Google, and they usually call that "partial decoupling":   the time derivative of $\delta_x$ depends only on the value of $\delta_x$, whereas the time derivative of $\delta_u$ depends in general on the values of $\delta_x$ and $\delta_u$.